# Can I use RavenDB (NoSQL) or should I just be using MySQL(RDBMS)?

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, ravendb

I am starting on a ASP.NET MVC 3 General Management System (Project Management being the first component).  Now I have been reading up a bit on RavenDB and it sounds pretty interesting.  One of the biggest things that I like about it is the fact I would not need any type on ORM to handle the data from the DB.  This will make my code a lot cleaner and quicker.  However coming from a background working exclusively with MySQL for the past 6+ years, I tend to think very relationally with my data.  There are a few things that seems like NoSQL would not be good for.  I want to throw these things out there and maybe these issues can be handle in a NoSQL solution and I am just think too relationally (then again, maybe this project should be done with MySQL).  These are the issues I am thinking of:

1. Unique Idenifiers: I am going to want to be able to have unique identifiers for a lot of things.  For stuff like projects, the name should be unique and could use that however when it come to tasks under a project, the title may not be unique and this is where I would use a quto-increment field but I can do that in RavenDB (from what I can tell)
2. Linking: Using for fields like status and type I would just use a linking with a foreign key.  Now for one-to-many relationships, I can just use the text instead of trying to link a foreign key (which you don't have in NoSQL) but with many-to-many linking, that because a problem.  For example, I intend to have a tagging system (like on here) where most items can have 1 to many tags attached to it and then I can perform searches on those tag for the items.  Is there a way to do this in NoSQL?

Is a RDBMS really the best tool for the job here or am I just not properly think the "NoSQL" way and I can accomplish this with NoSQL (RavenDB)?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post.  Perhaps the docs weren't as good when originally written.  But for reference in case other stumble here:

1. Raven comes with a HiLo document id generation strategy by default.  Storing a new document without specifying an id yourself will get an auto incrementing id such as "projects/1", "projects/2", etc.  Read more [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/basic-operations/saving-new-document).
2. The best guidance on the different ways to handle document relationships is [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/handling-document-relationships) in the documentation.  For the situation you described, you don't really need a separate document at all.  You can simply embed a string array of tag names into each item.  Documents are not flat, they can be structured. And yes, you can still query on them.

Hopefully you've discovered this on your own since the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Ayende wrote a post ["Modeling reference data in RavenDB"](http://ayende.com/blog/77825/modeling-reference-data-in-ravendb) which answers some of your questions re Linking.  You will have copies of the data between the reference document and your other documents and that redundancy is "ok" for document databases. You can still build indexes or query based on the on either Id or text that you store.

I would favor SQL for a transaction system such as Accounts Receivable application where you need to perform ad hoc queries.  With document database you really need to think through how you will be fetching your data and build indexes up front to answers those questions.  With RavenDB there is also a dynamic indexing function that learns from and caches the queries that are fired at the database.

For project management where the majority of items would be tasks I would think a RavenDB would fit your needs.